# Don't start next task and stop the flow whenever a task has error

Tags: java, runnable

I have many tasks that implement `Runnable` interface and have a method `hasError`. Whenever a task is not completed (`hasError` returns true) then the next task should not be started and the execution flow is stopped. How should I implement the ExecutorService to achieve this?

Comment: I already tried with a for loop with all tasks and check the hasError method whenever a task is submitted by using a while loop. If hasError returns false then breaking the for loop. I want to implement the ExecutorService to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Callable<T>` instead where the return value indicates if there is an error or not.

Answer (score 0):

[submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) returns a `Future`.  You can [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) the `Future`.  You may have to keep a list of all the futures though after you `submit` each `Runnable`.  You can have one more `Runnable` for cleanup that iterates this list, looking for things that have errored and if any have, then it `cancel`'s everyone.